# Changing the login screen wallpaper without changing the desktop wallpaper

Tags: release-freya, desktop, wallpaper, greeter

I want to have a separate wallpaper for my login screen which is not my desktop wallpaper. When I set a desktop wallpaper it is also set as the login  screen wallpaper and how can I use two different wallpapers. Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On beta versions of freya, in /usr/share/backgrounds where a file called something like "elementaryos-default-wallpaper" changing the name to "elementaryos-default-wallpaper.bak" and adding a image renamed to "elementaryos-default-wallpaper" change login screen. Not sure if it still works

This way you should change wallpaper on desktop, via right click on image, not in swichtboard, otherwise it will change also the login screen.

Comment: When I set as desktop background it still sets login screen

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is over a year old, but incase someone is still wondering; I managed to get a picture logon screen and plain coloured desktop on Loki like this:

1. in system settings/desktop select wallpaper; background and click on the coloured block in the bottom right corner.
2. I selected the colour I wanted (customised colour). this should now appear as the desktop background.
3. I then changed the "background" button (bottom left) to pictures and waited for my pictures folder to load my photos.
4. Select a picture and DOUBLE click it, this will now appear as the desktop.
5. Change the "picture" button back to "background" and if you scroll to the bottom you should find a picture which is just the colour selected in (2)
6. click ONCE on this picture and the desktop will change to this colour.
7. close system settings and logoff. You should now get your chosen picture on the logon screen and a plain coloured desktop when logged on.

Hopefully these instructions will adapt if you want a different pictures on logon and desktop screen.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack however in Loki (0.4.1) You can right-click on the login background image and set it as desktop, then through the command line enter the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///path/to/file
```

This will set the user's background image. Allowing you to have different images.

It's a bit hacky but it is the simplest way (2ish steps)

EG:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri file:///home/wwjdtd/pictures/801.png
```